# Multiplication of two asymptotic expansions

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

I have two functions $g, f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with asymptotic power series as follows:

For all $N\in\mathbb{N}:$

$$f(t) \sim \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n t^n + O(t^{N+1}) \text{ }\text{ }(\text{ as } t\downarrow 0)$$

and

$$g(t) \sim \frac{b_{-2}}{t} + \frac{b_{-1}}{\sqrt{t}} +  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} b_n t^n + O(t^{N+1}) \text{ }\text{ }(\text{ as } t\downarrow 0)$$

Now I want to deduce an asymptotic expansion for the product $f(t)\cdot g(t) $ for $t\downarrow 0$. How do I need to manipulate the above expressions to get an asymptotic expansion?

I suggest that the following can work. I get it by simple multiplication But I do not know how to prove it:

Claim: $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ one has:

$$f(t)\cdot g(t) \sim \frac{b_{-2}}{t}\cdot a_0 + \frac{b_{-1}}{\sqrt{t}}\cdot a_0 +  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \lbrace a_{n+1}b_{-2}+ a_{n+1}b_{-1}\sqrt{t} + \sum\limits_{\ell =0}^{n}a_{\ell}b_{n-\ell} \rbrace  t^n + O(t^{N+1}) \text{ }\text{ }(\text{ as } t\downarrow 0)$$

My problem is that $g(t)$ and its asymptotic expansion are not bounded in any neighborhood of $0$. Otherwise the proof would be very simple:

$$\vert f(t)\cdot g(t) - \frac{b_{-2}}{t}\cdot a_0 + \frac{b_{-1}}{\sqrt{t}}\cdot a_0 +  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \lbrace a_{n+1}b_{-2}+ a_{n+1}b_{-1}\sqrt{t} + \sum\limits_{\ell =0}^{n}a_{\ell}b_{n-\ell} \rbrace  t^n \vert \\
= \vert f(t)\cdot g(t) - \left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n t^n\right)\cdot \left( \frac{b_{-2}}{t} + \frac{b_{-1}}{\sqrt{t}} +  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} b_n t^n \right) \vert$$

Now I do not know how to proceed. Do you have any idea? Maybe my claim is even wrong and must be modified. 
The function $f(t)$ I'm interested in is actually very nice. Think about $f(t)=\exp(t)$ for instance.

Any help is very much appreciated,

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: You can put $t=u^2$, you have a Taylor expansion of $f(u^2)$, and also a Taylor expansion of $u^2g(u^2)$. Then you know how to find a Taylor expansion of $u^2g(u^2)f(u^2)$, and to finish you replace $u$ by $\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Hello Kelenner. If I do the calculations as you said it, I get exactly the same series as above, formally at least. So either I misunderstood you or the problem remains the same: Why is the above claim correct, i.e. why is the given formal series an asymptotic expansion for $f(t)\cdot g(t)$ ??

Comment: I think that multiplying $u^2g(u^2)$ by $f(u^2)$, as they are Taylor exopansion, you get $u^2g(u^2)f(u^2)=P(u)+O(u^{2N+2})$, $P$ a polynomial in $u$, valid for $u$ close to $0$. Now replacing $u$ by $\sqrt{t}$, you get an asymptotic expansion of $tg(t)f(t)$, valid for $t>0$ close to $0$. If suffice then to divide by $t$...If I am not wrong....

Comment: Ok, I understand now better. But if you do that, then you get the above series, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I think that in this way we find the same asymptotic expansion as you. It is only a justification to prove that your claim is correct.